# Lookup column in list not showing all possible fields

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, lookup

I'm creating a list in SharePoint Designer - we'll call it ListA - with a lookup column referring to ListB, but not all of the columns in ListB are showing up in the column editor for the lookup column in ListA.  The column that isn't showing up is a simple drop-down selector.

Any ideas as to why it's not showing up?

Answer (score 3):

this is a known issue.. even though, Microsoft states [here (in the .zip file)](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/blogs/GetThePoint/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=316) that Choice fields are valid lookup fields, it's not possible to select them column editor.

A workaround would be to create a calculated field in ListB and insert the choice column in the formular box. In ListA, instead of selecting the choice field, you select the calculated field - it will have the same data.

Comment: Tried doing this and it doesn't seem to work with the calculated field.  Will keep messing around with it to try and get it working.

Answer (score 0):

I found this article that can help you:

http://zimmergren.net/technical/sp-2010-how-to-relational-lists-in-sharepoint-2010

Note:It works for me but just for one level of hierarchy.